# Drag and drop cross browser [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, drag-and-drop

So the intention of this is that I can drag and drop div's on a time-scheme, which works fine! The div's show a small time-box on top of the div you're holding to show you a specific time you're dropping you div on.

The problem comes when doing this cross browser, you can drag and drop this div from other windows, which works as intended.
BUT the clock besides the div you're holding doesn't activate, and thus you don't know exactly where to put this div in your time scheme.

[image]
This is me dragging the orange box over the time-scheme, and as you can see there is a time besides the div I'm dragging to show the time more specific.
This clock isn't being shown when dragging the div from cross browser.

Comment: What drag and drop library are you using. Or is this Native HTML5 Drag and Drop? A code example would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not using any drag and drop library at all, just jQuery as a common library @SeanLarkin